# How to detect name of another variable but not his value javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, variables, value-of

In the js code I have

```
var a1 = "text in a1";
var right_text = a1;
```

`a1` is the variable where this text is written.
the value of `right_text` will change.
I need have more variables like `a1` because each of them will do something else.

```
  switch (right_text) {
     case a1:
...
     case a2:
...
     case a3:
...
```

I would like it to increase value of `right_text` to `a2` after first click on the button and to `a3` after another click and so on.
So I want to get the variable `a1` as a `string`,  add one and get `a2`.

But now I need to somehow detect the current value of `right_text`, ie `a1`, not the content written in `a1`.

I tried

```
right_text.toString ();
```

But that will return the mentioned content `a1`. It could be done somehow so that I can get value of `right_text` (`a1` in this case) and convert it as `string`?
Thank you

Comment: an array?.........

Comment: Yes, but I need to use swich - case1 -case2 too. What I would write instead case a1? Would it be for example `case myarray[1]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that right_text is a current step var.
You can set base value for right_text and a counter.

```
var right_text = 'a';
var step_counter = 0;
```

When the user click on your button, increase a counter.

```
step_counter++;
```

Now, you can set the current step text :

```
right_text = 'a' + step_counter;
```

When you display right_text, your output will be like that :

```
'' => 0 clicks
'a1' => First click
'a2' => Second click
```

```js
var right_text = '';
var step_counter = 0;

function countMe() {
  step_counter++;
  right_text = 'a' + step_counter;
  document.getElementById( 'currentVal' ).innerHTML = right_text;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="countMe();"> Click Me ! </button><br/>
<p id='resultText'>
  Current Value : <span id="currentVal"></span>
</p>
```